# how to open file if it exists otherwise redirect to a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

iam trying to tell the page to open a certain aspx if it exists otherwise it should redirect to another page here the code iam using:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "~/User" + "/" + Page.User.Identity.Name + "/" + Page.User.Identity.Name + ".aspx";
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(str);
    if (fi.Exists) {
        Response.Redirect(str);
    }
    else {
    Response.Redirect("Page.aspx");
        }
}
```

but i will always redirect to the page.aspx even if the original page exists

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the full path to FileInfo. Use [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) to map from your virtual path to a full path, like this:

```
string str = "~/User" + "/" + Page.User.Identity.Name + "/" + Page.User.Identity.Name + ".aspx";
string path = Server.MapPath(str);
if (File.Exists(path)) 
{
    Response.Redirect(str);
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("Page.aspx");
}
```

Comment: unfortunately because im using filestream to create the page i cannot use _server.mappath_ instead of ~ because it will not create the file as i want it.

Comment: @Wahtever - can you elaborate?   Once the file is created,  Server.MapPath() should work the same way, regardless of how the file was created.

Comment: yes you are right (sorry.my mistake) what i meant was it gave me an error _cannot map the path_ but i am sure that the file is there. agian sorry.

Comment: What is the value of the string when you call `Server.MapPath` ? MapPath will map to a physical path, even if that physical path doesn't exist.

Comment: it throws an error cannot map the path ( i basically used the code you wrote)

Comment: I can't see what should be wrong. Please update your question with full exception type, message and stack trace you are getting, as well as the exact string passed into `MapPath`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it is because you are using ~.  ~ is used for resolving the web URL base path.   Not the windows base path.

Instead of

```
string str = "~/User" + "/" + Page.User.Identity.Name + "/" + Page.User.Identity.Name + ".aspx";
```

try

```
string str = Server.MapPath("/User" + "/" + Page.User.Identity.Name + "/" + Page.User.Identity.Name + ".aspx"")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be careful with the ~ path alias. I'd try using an absolute path instead of the alias and see if that helps. If it's always redirecting to `Page.aspx` then the file you think you're looking at doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the ~

```
string str = string.Format("/User/{0}/{0}.aspx",Page.User.Identity.Name);
string path = Server.MapPath(str)
```